# Sampling MaxEnt Distribution with PyMC3

Tags: machine-learning, python, pymc, maximum-entropy

I’m trying to use `PyMC3` to sample from a maximum entropy distribution over binary patterns of length $N$, constrained by means and pairwise correlations. The distribution is given by:

$$P(X)=\frac{1}{Z}\exp\left({\displaystyle-\sum_i{\alpha_ix_i}-\sum_{i\ne j}{\beta_{ij}x_ix_j}}\right)$$

and is parameterized by the alpha and beta coefficients.

I’ve started with the simplest example, in which the beta coefficients are zero and the alphas are not. I began with synthesizing data:

```
data = pm.Model()
alphas = np.array([-1,-2,0.5,3.5])
with data:
    X = pm.DiscreteUniform('X', lower=0, upper=1, shape=4)
    constraints = pm.math.dot(alphas,X)
    potential = pm.Potential("potential", constraints.sum())
    datatrace = pm.sample(4000, step=BinaryMetropolis(vars=[X]))
```

Then, I tried to learn these parameters from the data:

```
model = pm.Model()
with model:
    coeffs = pm.Normal('coeffs', mu=0, sd=1, shape=datatrace['X'].shape[1])
    constraints = pm.math.dot(coeffs,datatrace['X'].T)
    potential = pm.Potential("potential", constraints.sum()) 
    tr = pm.sample(4000)
```

But I get very weird results…

I’d appreciate help in understanding:

1. What am I doing wrong at the moment in inferring the alphas.
2. How to include the beta coefficients in the model (both for simulating data and inference purposes).

**EDIT**: 
The sampler *had* converged to a stable solution `coeffs=[1534.993,1686.984,1977.998,2277.013]`, but not to the desired solution `alphas = np.array([-1,-2,0.5,3.5])` from the data generating part…